# What's wrong with my code while populating Listview from SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

Following s my Code to display data to listview from database. But it will not work and crash my application.please  Give perfect solution for my this problem.

My Code......

```
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.deletestudent);
           // DisplayStudent();


        ArrayList<String > arrlst=new ArrayList<String>();
         ListView lst_stu=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);

            db.open();
            Cursor cur=db.GetStudent();

            for (int i=0;i<cur.getCount();i++)
            {
                cur.moveToFirst();

                String stunm=cur.getString(1);
                arrlst.add(1, stunm);
                lst_stu.setAdapter((ListAdapter) arrlst);

                 db.close();
            }

    }
```

Comment: Why are you setting the adapter and closing the database inside your for loop?

Comment: thanks now i will change my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try Below Code

```
try
    {
        Cursor cursor = null;

        db.OpenDatabase();
        cursor = db.GetStudent();

        // Here if condition check wheather the cursor returns record or not.
        // If cursor has some records then it will return non zero number .

        if (cursor.getCount() != 0) 
        {
            // Here if condition check wheather the cursor move to first record or not
            // If it moves to first record then it will return true.
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) 
            {
                do 
                {
                    arrlst.add(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("your_field_in_database")).trim());

                }while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.closeDatabase();
        lst_stu.setAdapter((ListAdapter) arrlst);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Dear it will not give any error but it is not display data in to list view.

Comment: i am getting output of my that problem.

Comment: i have another problem while  i m configure phonegap with eclipse. if have any solution then send to me plz..

Answer (score 2):

```
        for (int i=0;i<cur.getCount();i++)
        {
            cur.moveToFirst();

            String stunm=cur.getString(1);
            arrlst.add(1, stunm);
            lst_stu.setAdapter((ListAdapter) arrlst);

             db.close();
        }
```

The problem is that you are closing the cursor in the first iteration.

> > Give perfect solution for my this problem.

You look like my boss, excepts that he pays 20 dollars per hour....

Whatever, there are a lot of things which are bad in your code, mostly because you don't understand how a cursor works:

- Why do you call `moveToFirst` on each iteration? Does it make sens for you?
- Why do you close the cursor inside the for?
- Why do you set the adapter on each iteration?
- Why do you use an array adapter instead of `CursorAdapter`?

Comment: sorry Dear. but people will learn something when they do mistake.

Comment: now i got solution of my problem and it will work because of your guide. thanks once again.

Comment: Oh, yes... that's a trial-error methodology. It's fine, but you could try another better methodology to learn: READ. If you someday learn to *read*, you will not only learn *something* but also save a lot time.